# What will be the effect of deleting C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET? Will windows continue to work?

Tags: .net-framework, runtime

I know that .Net programs will fail to run if the CLR IS DELETED, but Im just curious about windows itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One wouldn't think that Windows would allow critical parts of itself to be placed in the
Installed Programs (Add/Remove) list with uninstallation just a click away. I've never heard that .Net Framework is in any way essential. If you really want to be rid of it, I would advise using the regular uninstall method, rather than just deleting the files and leaving
an unholy mess of dangling registry references behind.

Comment: sweeeeeeeeeeeeeet